# Sites/ways helpful for learning internet/slang lingo?

Tags: slang, dialects, resources, website, internet-slang

As the title says- I'm wondering if anyone is aware of a website used for learning dialects and internet lingo?

Comment: This seems to be an open-ended question without a single correct answer and as such risks being closed unless you can reword it to be less open.

Comment: Ah sorry, still not used to the site. Then I suppose this sort of question should instead be asked in the chat or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a zokugo dictionary [here](http://zokugo-dict.com/), which includes both normal slang and internet slang. Of course, it's all in Japanese.

I haven't been able to find any other resources for this sort of thing, though.

Comment: That's the kind of thing I was looking for, huge thanks!